# Postman validation, Getting AssertionError: VAR: expected 'createdTime' to deeply equal 'VAR'

Tags: assertion

I'm trying to verify the value created as part of the response, value is the same found in the global variable set in previous request within same collection.

Anything you can advise or try?

Tests:

```
pm.test("Created Time is present", function () {
    pm.expect("createdTime", pm.response.json().createdTime).to.be.eql(pm.globals.get("createdTime"));
});
```

Response:

> Created Time is present | AssertionError: 2020-03-31T20:07:15Z:
>   expected 'createdTime' to deeply equal '2020-03-31T20:07:15Z'

Comment: Formatted code, highlighted response

Answer (score 0):

Correct assertion in your case is:

```
pm.test("Created Time is present", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.createdTime).to.eql(pm.variables.get("createdTime"));
});
```